# How to make a function access to only one file?

Tags: c, scope, include, private

### What I want

I have two files: `file.h` and `file.c`. I want to define a function in `file.h` that is going to have its definition in `file.c` but I don't want the function to be included when I include `file.h` in other file.

### Example:

**file.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_INCLUDED

// This function should be declared here and defined in "file.c"
// but only used there (not in any other source file).
int private_func();

// This function can be used every where (if included of course)
// but it needs to be able to access the "private_func()".
int public_func();

#endif // HEADER_INCLUDED
```

**file.c**

```c
#include "file.h"

int private_func()
{
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;

  return a + b;
}

int public_func()
{
  // this functons uses the "private_func()" result to give its result
  int c = private_func();
  int d = private_func();

  return c + d; 
}

#endif // HEADER_INCLUDED
```

**other.c**
This file should not import `private_func()` when including its header

```c
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
  // can call the "public_func()"
  int result1 = public_func();
  
  // but cannot call "private_func()"
  int result2 = private_func();

  return 0;
}
```

### In short

I don't want private_func() to be imported by a file other than "file.c". (if possible)

Comment: In `file.c` you can define the private function as `static` so it won't be visible to other modules.

Comment: Then don't put `private_func` in `file.h`. Just put `int private_func();` in `file.c` and make it `static`.

Comment: A header is used to share information with source files.  If you don't want other files to use something, don't put it in the header.  Any function not declared in a header should be static in the file where it is defined.

Comment: The preprocessor hack makes most sense if the full project has more than one implementation file that needs the private function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the pre-processor.  In header:

```
#ifndef HEADER_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_INCLUDED

#ifdef _USE_PRIVATE_
// This function should be declared here and defined in "file.c"
// but only used there (not in any other source file).
int private_func();
#endif

// This function can be used every where (if included of course)
// but it needs to be able to access the "private_func()".
int public_func();

#endif // HEADER_INCLUDED
```

In the implementation file:

```
#define _USE_PRIVATE_
#include "file.h"

int private_func()
{
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;

  return a + b;
}

int public_func()
{
  // this functons uses the "private_func()" result to give its result
  int c = private_func();
  int d = private_func();

  return c + d; 
}

#endif // HEADER_INCLUDED
```

other.c would not change.  Including the header without the special define would omit the private definition.